# TestFlight information

Tags: ios, objective-c

iam trying to use external test flight , but it ask me to fill this form what is the info should I fill with ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to testing information.The internal & external testers will give feedback about your app once tested & if need they will contact based on your info which you are going to fill.

Using Sign in information you can give testing credentials to testers to sign in your app.

Simply click the

> Question mark '?' it will give you enough details.